# Multiple key/value pairs in JSON field as query param

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql table with following records (json for your convinience):

```
[
    {
        "field": "example1",
        "jsonfield": {"name": "name1", "option": "option1}
    },
    {
        "field": "example2",
        "jsonfield": {"name": "name2", "option": "option2}
    },
    {
        "field": "example3",
        "jsonfield": {"name": "name3", "option": "option3}
    }
]
```

Now I have list of multiple suitable key/value pairs to Select from this table

```sql
SELECT 
    field, jsonfield
FROM table
WHERE jsonfield @> ANY (ARRAY['{"name": "name1", "option": "option1}', '{"name": "name3", "option": "option3}']::jsonb[])
```

It works well and returns first and third record

However, I want to pass array as query param

```sql
SELECT 
    field, jsonfield
FROM table
WHERE jsonfield @> ANY (ARRAY[(:search_data)]::jsonb[])
```

And this raises the following error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR: cannot cast type record to jsonb
```

How do I pass the array as a query param?
Should I use something like string_to_array?

I use PostgreSQL 13.3

Comment: And if I don't use `ARRAY`, I receive `"[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.`

Comment: To answer this part `How do I pass the array as a query param?` we would need to know what language or even framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be (depending on the language)

```
... WHERE jsonfield @> ANY (cast(:search_data as jsonb[]))
```

You have to either send the search_data parameter as an array (very much depends on the language, the libraries and what is supported) or as a the array string syntax. The array string syntax is as follows:

Opening curly brace `{` is closed by `}`.

Element list uses divider `,` for nearly all value types. I believe the ones that used another divider were spacial/geometric types.

Each element if it is a string or string-representable MUST be quoted IF it contains:

1. a double-quote
2. the divider
3. an opening or closing brace
4. it is a string consisting of `"null"`. Case-insensitive.

Escaping the double-quote within a string is done with backslash.

Strings and string-representables are quoted using double-quotes.

examples:

1. `ARRAY[DATE '2020-06-01', DATE '2021-06-01']` becomes `{2020-06-01,2021-06-01}`
2. an array containing `please, don't` and `include` becomes `{"please, don't",include}` or `{"please, don't","include"}`
3. An array containing `He said "don't do it"` would become `{"He said \"don't do it\""}`

[Sample with raw queries](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3USskDD2QsF2mtE26jR92F/0)

Comment: Currently the only type that uses a delimiter other than comma is the geometric box. It's the only one in [pg_type.dat](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/catalog/pg_type.dat) with a non-default `typdelim` value.